# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1-\cos(z))}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried to find the residue of the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1-\cos(z))}$$ at the $z=0$. So I did:

\begin{align}
\hbox{Res}(0)&=\lim_{x \to 0}(z)(f(z))\\
\hbox{Res}(0)&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}
\end{align}

and I got that the residue to be $\infty$, and it seems to be wrong.

Comment: The formula you used only works for simple poles. You've got a pole of higher order there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^2(z/2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z(1-\cos(z))}
&=\frac2{z^3}\left(\frac{z/2}{\sin(z/2)}\right)^2\\
&=\frac2{z^3}\left(\frac1{1-\frac1{24}z^2+O\!\left(z^4\right)}\right)^2\\
&=\frac2{z^3}\left(1+\frac1{12}z^2+O\!\left(z^4\right)\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac2{z^3}+\color{#C00}{\frac1{6z}}+O\!\left(z\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos z=1-\dfrac{1}{2!}z^2+\dfrac{1}{4!}z^4-\dfrac{1}{6!}z^6+\cdots$$
then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{z(1-\cos z)}
&= \dfrac{1}{z^3\left(\dfrac{1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{4!}z^2+\dfrac{1}{6!}z^4+\cdots\right)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{z^3}\left(2+\dfrac{1}{6}z^2+\dfrac{1}{120}z^4+\cdots\right) \\
&= \dfrac{2}{z^3}+\dfrac{1}{6z}+\dfrac{z}{120}+\cdots
\end{align}
s0 $a_{-1}=\dfrac16$.